# getting Json in to a list in flex flash builder mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

I using Flash builder 4.5 and calling my own webservice which return a json with four fields, but many records.

I use the Data/Service to create the service and when I use the "Test Operation" I get the first record with the four fields, if I change to raw view I see five records.

My problem when I bind it to a list I only get the first record, regardless if I return the result as an array or arraycollection. I have a Data Type called NoName1 which have four fields.

My question is how to get the result from a json into a list,the way I do it now will only show the first record in the list.

Thanks,
Kim

```
  <s:CallResponder id="Operation1Result" result="Operation1Result.lastResult as NoName1"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not clear what is the actual question. Probably you should rephrase, so it is easier to understand your goal. Also, I'd advise to consult the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash builder 4.5.1 takes care of the deserializing of the json. I found the problem, the json from the website was not formatted corretly

Answer (score 0):

To decode JSON you can use the [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) library

Comment: Flash builder 4.5.1 takes care of the deserializing of the json. I found the problem, the json from the website was not formatted corretly.